# What is the result of xgb-wrapper cross-validation (xgb.cv)?

Tags: python, cross-validation, xgboost

I can't understand the output of xgb.cv: 
1) is it the result of one k-fold or the best k-fold?
2) and on what principle is data set splitted on training and test sets - KFold or 0.8/0.2?

When I run the code, I see the calculation process. It stops after early stopping rounds on the best score.

Of course: # model parameters

```
num_parallel_tree = 1 
subsample = 1 
colsample_bytree = 0.4
objective = 'binary:logistic'
learning_rate = 0.05
eval_metric = 'auc'
max_depth = 10
min_child_weight = 4

n_estimators = 5000
seed = 7

#cross-validation parameters
nfold = 5
early_stopping_rounds = 5


bst_cv = xgb.cv(
    param, 
    dtrain,  
    num_boost_round=n_estimators, 
    nfold = nfold,
    early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
    verbose_eval=True
)

results:
[0] train-auc:0.910342+0.0015485    test-auc:0.850442+0.00619299
[1] train-auc:0.956268+0.00132653   test-auc:0.893746+0.00973467
...
[24]    train-auc:0.984302+0.000617268  test-auc:0.934326+0.00338043
```

and then - stops.

Comment: could you provide the variable : param to us? This is your set-up, and also what number is nfold?

Comment: Of course: i've added it to code in the topic. thank you.